# How to convert price values to ranks in excel pivot table rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel pivot table where column A is the date, column B is the price of product 1 in $, column C the price of product 2, column D the price of product 3. So it's showing the prices of products 1, 2 and 3 on different dates over many weeks.

I want to know the rank of each product on each date for the whole dataset, e.g. on date 1, product 1 ranks highest (rank 1), product 2 ranks next (rank 2) and product 3 ranks lowest (rank 3), on date 2, product 1 ranks lowest....etc. So each price converts to a number representing its rank compared to the other prices in that row (date).

I've tried right clicking on a cell and choosing 'show values as' and clicking 'rank smallest to largest'. This gives the prompt to choose the base field, which it suggests should be the date. However, when I click ok the values that the prices are converted to are not the correct ranks. I have tried to figure out what the new values are but I'm lost. They look like they are ranks (they're whole numbers) but they're definitely not the ranks of the prices in that row in relation to each other.

Any suggestions? Thank you so much.

Christina

Comment: Here's some more detail to help. These are the prices in the first row of data (46 different price values  - for 46 different products) ranging from $0.6 to $19500 depending on the product): 03 March 2011 7.65 14 4.6 0.65 7.25 1.85 1590 3.8 4.3 19500 6.9 3.5 4.5 10.7 1.8 1.67 8.9 9.75 10.5 4.5 5.5 3.8 15.75 8.9 5 12 3.15 7 7 10.9 6.05 7.65 7.8 9.25 7.5 20 0.6 7.8 1 1 7.95 7.7 7.2 7 1455 6. I want to be able to convert the lowest (0.6) to 1 (indicating lowest ranking value) and convert 19500 to 46 (highest ranking value). And of course convert all the other values to their correct ranks.

Comment: Or another option I'd be equally happy with would be to create a new column for each of the 46 products showing the rank of its price for each date (adding new columns in which to calculate the ranks rather than converting the prices to ranks). I don't know how to do that either, if it is possible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do not clarify your question in comments, especially by adding examples of poorly formatted data. Rather **edit** your question to improve it there, keeping the data as **text**. Also include at least a screenshot of your desired results from the data you post.

Comment: The problem with using the rank pivot table function inside the pivot table is Excel compares the order of data per column and not per row. Look at adding a formula next to the pivot table, using the rank function in a formula, e.g. `=RANK(E4, E4:G4, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you @Mobus, I've done that and it's giving me the right answer. But I'm not managing to copy the formula down (I have 46 columns and 275 rows). This is the  formula (edited a bit to make it short enough to fit here) when I change 'number' to the price for the first date for the first product: =RANK(GETPIVOTDATA("Unit price",$A$3,"Date number (single)",DATE(2011,3,4)",59),B9:AN9, 1). When I copy the formula down the date remains the same (i.e. 2011,3,4) instead of changing to 2011,3,5. The ref does change correctly. Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @RonRosenfeld for the advice. I didn't know how to add a screenshot.

Comment: Indeed, formula references to pivot data are absolute. Sometimes it helps to just and paste all the pivot table data into a new sheet "as values" (i.e. no longer a pivot table)

Comment: To add screenshots, simply press ALT+Print Screen, or use the Windows Snipping Tool. The image will now be in your windows clipboard. Open you superuser  question and hit CTRL+V to paste the image at the appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks. I've considered that, but I'm hoping to keep using the pivot table because if any of my raw data changes I'd need to manually update the new pasted table. It's quite possible that will happen and it could lead to errors later. Do you mean there's no way to do what I'm describing? Ah - and thanks for the info on screenshots.

Comment: It is far better to add the data as **text** which can be copy/pasted than as a screenshot.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).  And also this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: You can also try to give a screenshot about the data and result here.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to fix this problem. Instead of clicking on the cell in the pivot table to add the first 'number' to the rank formula, I manually wrote the cell number (B7) into the rank formula. This has allowed me to generate a whole table of rank values as I was hoping. Thanks for the suggestions that helped me get there!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).